# What is the reason for AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'TclError'?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, compiler-errors

```
        from six.moves.tkinter import Canvas, Tk
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
      File "/home/sheetal/environments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
        mod = mod._resolve()
```

I get this error when importing nltk or matplotlib. I am running on python 3.6 virtual environment.
          File "/home/sheetal/envir

```
onments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/home/sheetal/environments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    TclError = tkinter.TclError
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'TclError'
```

Answer (score 0):

Open /usr/local/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py with a text editor, and replace:

```
TclError = tkinter.TclError
```

with:

```
TclError = _tkinter.TclError
```

If this works I think your tkinter files are corrupted, and I'd suggest you reinstall them:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-tk
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```